# Navigation Drawer Customization

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation, navigation-drawer

Hii all I am not good at designing. I need help with the following layout.
1-How to add the images right next to pay(Subscription) , like we add badge?
2-How to set the view , like it is when we select an item in the image below? Showing a light blue marker at the start of it.
3-How to add the bottom blue footer line?

P.s. My navigation view is also very slow. Any tips on that would be helpful too. [image]

Comment: 1-How to add the images right next to pay(Subscription) --> remove Padding or margin added to pay textview and  icons imageview 2) for the 2nd one you should do a click event to image view and do the animations

Comment: For the bottom footer line add this XML and adjust with your conditions-->                                         
          <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:background="#0000FF"
            android:id="@+id/view" />

Comment: Actually I am having trouble adding images. The distance isn't the issue. I don't know how to add the image actually.

Comment: In the menu items layout?

Comment: This is my menu layout . <group
         android:id="@+id/grp6"
         android:checkableBehavior="single">
 <item
         android:id="@+id/menu__list_pay_subscription"
         android:title="@string/List_paid_Subs" />
 </group>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138625/discussion-between-john-simon-and-syeda-sundus-bokhari).

Comment: add icon in item tag then.First make an image with alll banks then save it in drawable   ex: android:icon="@drawable/help"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Initializing my navigation drawer , I did this.

```
 gallery=(TextView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(navigationView.getMenu().
            findItem(R.id.menu__pay_subscription));

    initializeCountDrawer();
```

Then The method.

```
   private void initializeCountDrawer(){
    gallery.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    gallery.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    gallery.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    Drawable img = context.getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.cards);
    img.setBounds( 0, 0, 200, 40 );
    gallery.setCompoundDrawables( img, null, null, null);

}
```